# Как правильно отправлять сообщения в телеграм из других [TelegramBots]

Tags: java, telegram, telegrambots

Я пишу бота и я хочу использовать функцию `execute(...)` за пределами класса с `extend TelegramLongPollingBot`. На данный момент я делаю так:

`new BotName().execute(sendMessage);`

Пример использования данной строки в методе:

```
public String sendMessage(PostAPI message){
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
        sendMessage.setChatId(message.getChatId());
        sendMessage.setText(message.getText());
        sendMessage.setParseMode(ParseMode.MARKDOWNV2);
        try {
            Message message1 = new BotName().execute(sendMessage);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "test";
    }
```

На мой взгляд, данный способ является не самым лучшим и я хотел бы узнать правильный вариант вызова метода `execute(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный способ это создать один экземпляр класса, который наследует `TelegramLongPollingBot`, и использовать его.

Вот пример из [документации](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/blob/dev/TelegramBots.wiki/understanding-the-library/Understanding-The-Library.md#the-library-and-the-bot-api):

```
// We initialize our bot in a separate method. See this as the initialization code from the getting started guide
AbsSender ourBot = getOurBot();

// We create the Method class. This one doesn't need any parameters to be able to be send
GetMe getMe = new GetMe();

// At last, we just need to execute the method and get the result
User bot = ourBot.execute(getMe);
```

Тут пример с `GetMe`, но для `SendMessage` все ровно то же.

Теперь, что такое `getOurBot()` в этом примере. Это функция, которая возвращает созданный экземпляр бота.

Конечно подход описаный в документации нужно адаптировать под структуру вашего кода. В вашей программе есть место, где происходит создание бота. Что-то в таком духе:

```
ApiContextInitializer.init();

TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();

try {
    botsApi.registerBot(new BotName());
} catch (TelegramApiException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Нужно экземпляр сохранить и использовать в классе, в котором определен метод `sendMessage` (например передать его в конструктор и сохранить для дальнейшего использования):

```
class MyClass {

  private BotName bot;

  public MyClass(BotName bot) {
    this.bot = bot;
  }

  public String sendMessage(PostAPI message){
    SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
    sendMessage.setChatId(message.getChatId());
    sendMessage.setText(message.getText());
    sendMessage.setParseMode(ParseMode.MARKDOWNV2);
    try {
      Message message1 = bot.execute(sendMessage);
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "test";
  }
}
```

Comment: Могли бы Вы добавить инициализацию MyClass c методом `sendMessage(..)` для наглядности? А так - спасибо за ответ!